# Strange and Incorrect Excel Formulas Result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to get the length of a formula result, but it returns incorrectly.

For example, I put `1005` in the cell `A1`, put the formula `=(A1/1000-FLOOR(A1/1000,1))*1000` into `B1` and the result is `5`, that's correct. But when I put the formula `=LEN(B1)` into the cell `C1`, the result is `16`? Even worse, the formula `=REPT(0,3-LEN(TEXT(B1,"0")))&(B1)` or `=REPT(0,3-LEN(TEXT((A1/1000-FLOOR(A1/1000,1))*1000,"0")))&((A1/1000-FLOOR(A1/1000,1))*1000)` returns `004.99999999999989`??

Comment: Floating-point error :-) More reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/).

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you want to get the text length of the text returned by a formula computation? If so, won't the LEN and TEXT functions accomplish that for you?

Comment: round the result.. before get the length. ( :

Comment: @MarkFernandes Since `5` is in the cell `B1`, I just wonder to know why `=LEN(B1)` returns `16`...

Comment: @TRX: I'm not sure why either. It could be that the `LEN` function is trying to calculate the text length of the formula rather than the result. If the `LEN` function is mistakenly operating on the assumption of a 2-byte unicode encoding, when in fact a 1-byte ASCII encoding is being used, then that could explain the return value of 16 [half of 32, 32 being the formula character length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `=LEN(B1)` returns 16 is because the value in cell `B1` may be *displayed* as `5`, but it is actually *stored* internally as `4.99999999999989` - and that number has 16 characters in it, when evaluated as a string by `LEN()`.

You can see this for yourself by repeatedly clicking on the "Increase Decimal" button:

[image]

Here, the display eventually has enough decimal places to reflect the underlying value (the `LEN` function ignores trailing zeroes - again, those are *display* zeroes not stored zeroes).

You can also see the same thing if you simply enter the following formula into a cell:

```
=1.005-1
```

This actually has 19 characters in it, not 16, because we have not multiplied by 1,000:

```
0.00499999999999989
```

The loss of precision from your displayed `5` to the actual stored `4.99999999999989` is indeed because of how floating point math works, as mentioned by BigBen.

See also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a broader discussion.